# Can we auto-flag edits to previously disputed posts?

Tags: feature-request, edits, flags, moderator-tools

One scenario I've run into several times now that I wish had been instantly brought to a moderator's attention is the case of edits to posts that have previously been locked for a content dispute. It would be nice to raise an auto-flag any time this happens so that a further dispute can be headed off. Sometimes the original trouble maker comes back after the lock timeout, sometimes another editor will try to "fix" something that previously got reverted by the author, etc. Most of the time these are not good edits. Only very astute editors will have checked the log to see what's been worked on before and not revisit the same problems.

I'm not sure if this would require extra limits. Possibilities that come to mind are:

- Only the first edit after a dispute vs. any future ones.
- Only if the edit was from an author who edited any time before the dispute.

...but I think for starters just flagging all post-dispute edits would be helpful.

Answer (score 8):

I can see where you're coming from, but I think moderator flags are just going to result (on busy sites, at least) in a lot of moderators getting a lot of flags that they don't really care about; there's probably not much need for moderators to be flagged for every attempt at an edit, and a "first edit" or "previously involved users" flag would probably just be too localized to be particularly useful (I, for example, have seen numerous cases of problematic posts being revisited months after the fact, or even longer, and often not by the same <strike>user</strike> account).

In this vein, the following mechanism strikes me as ideal for handling future edits on disputed posts:

- When a post has been locked for content-dispute (or maybe even after it reaches a threshold of rollbacks), add a persistent "disputed"  to the post after the lock expires.  Maybe automatically display a post-notice.
- Future attempts to edit the post will display a warning, either linking to the relevant meta discussion or, at least, warning users that this has a history of dispute and to check the revision history for details.
- Edits go into the suggested edit queue rather than getting applied immediately, even if the user has the edit privilege; probably safe for high-rep users (i.e. those with access to moderator tools) to forego this step.

  - Maybe add a new "rejected" reason when the suggested edit is on a "disputed" post, along the lines of "Just re-opens the same damned can of worms we welded shut in 2003" (exact wording is open to suggestion, but I think I nailed it here…).
- The "disputed" would naturally decay after a while (e.g. enough approved edits, or a certain threshold of approved:rejected edits, or after a certain time or number of views without activity, I dunno.  Basically just a point when "This post ain't appear to be particularly disputed no more.").

For bonus points, adding a pane to /tools/stats which lists recent activity to "disputed" posts would allow moderators and power users to still easily keep tabs on things at their own pace without drowning anybody in flags.

Accelerating things to moderator level could still be useful if the disputed post continues to get a large number of rejected edits (or especially if certain users repeatedly suggest rejected edits), but this seems the sort of thing the community itself could probably handle in most cases, and the review queue seems exactly suitable for that.